# ASP.NET 5, Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package, not found error in ASP.NET 5 beta3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET MVC 6 application, which calls some external web service.
I use this guide: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace TestService.Web.Code
{
    internal class ServiceProxy
    {
        internal string Get(string predicate)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("TestService/LookupService" +
                                                                         "/GetCountries?term={0}", predicate)).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                     var answer = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                     return answer;
                }

                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But here is unexpected problem: I have 3 errors after build project:

- Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'HttpClient' could not be found
- Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue' could not be found
- Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'HttpResponseMessage' could not be found

Looks like Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client package version not compatible with my KRE version.

Am I right? And how can I fix this?

Here is project.json content:

```
{

    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22605",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta3"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0",
            "System.Net": "4.0.0.0"
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0-beta-22605"
        }
    }
},
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
],
"bundleExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
]
}
```

Comment: can you post your project.json file?

Comment: sorry, forgot about project.json. done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly right. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package is being used both for clrcore and clr runtimes in your example. This package can only be used for clr runtime.

With the latest changes (renames and all that), here is a working piece:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    internal class ServiceProxy
    {
        internal string Get(string predicate)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8001/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(string.Format("TestService/LookupService" +
                                                                         "/GetCountries?term={0}", predicate)).Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                     var answer = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                     return answer;
                }

                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

project.json:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { 
            "dependencies": {
                                "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client": "5.2.3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I did File --> New project --> Web --> ASP.NET 5 Console Application, then I copied content of your project.json and Program.cs, 
then did restore packages. Unfortunately problem still remains(

Comment: I forgot about Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client! It works now!